# Does folder exist in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php

I want to create a simple search if a "folder" exists. If it doesn't I want a notification similar to form_validation error.

But if the folder does exist the process continues.

I've developed the coding below but it doesn't work.

```
if(!is_dir('members/$boss'))
$this->form_error('$boss', 'The boss username does not exist');
```

I want an error notification the same as "The boss username does not exist"

But if the folder does exist then the process continues.

I've searched many sites including Stack Overflow which some come close but not precisely what I want.

Can anybody guide me?

Update 28/08/19

I have changed the coding to 1 line as follows;

```
if(!file_exists("members/$boss")) die ("UsernameDoesntExist");
```

It works but the notification appears on a blank page.

If I insert the following into the view page I get the text box and the notification, but without the submit button and again on a blank page.

```
<?php die ("UsernameDoesntExist"); ?>
```

The same applies if I replace "die" with "exit".

I understand this is because "die" & "exit" terminates the PHP scripting.

I have tried "echo", "print", "goto", "return" & a few others but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes

```
if(!is_dir("members/$boss"));
$this->form_error("$boss", 'The boss username does not exist');
```

Comment: OK thank you but I now get an error with "form_error". That is if I put in the wrong username. If I put the right username it redirects as it should. Any suggestions as to what I should replace "form_error" with?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283642/codeigniter-form-error-displays-only-one-error?rq=1

Comment: That page covers validation issues. My problem is only "similar" to a validation error. I've already tried many validation codings.

Comment: @inckie can you shed some light on this problem?